# Why CF8 encoded cfm file doesn't work in CF9 server?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-9

I've stuck at this problem. Our old-old programmers have encoded their CFM file based on CF8 and I cannot find the original file in our server. Recently, I've deployed these encoded CF8 files into CF9. Unfortunately, these encoded CF8 files don't work in CF9 server?

Please let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sure. It's in the same directory.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question with information about the error you're seeing.

Comment: is it in different OS? back to 2006 when using cf 7, we use fedora as development server, tested the compiled source code with different linux and windows (never tested on mac) and with cf 8 it's still OK, until we upgrade the development server to cf 9, no error message occured and it's only show a blank page. still doesnt know why, but luckily we have the original source :D

Comment: Sure, it's different OS. W2k to Win 2008r2. I don't think different OS will be relevant to my problem. I bet, it's because different version of CFML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, if you search online for cfdecrypt you will likely find a tool to produce plain text source from the encoded version.  CFEncode doesn't truly encrypt the code, but merely obfuscates it.  The cfdecrypt tool has been passed around the web for many years, and was not developed by Allaire/Macromedia/Adobe, so caveat emptor.

Comment: I've tried and search cfdecrypt but cannot download it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Originally by Matthew Chapman, I've posted both the Windows and Linux versions here with source code and a helper bash script. https://github.com/disccomp/cfdecrypt

Answer (score 0):

The CFEncode utility hasn't changed in many years.  Files encoded with it several versions ago will work in the latest versions of ColdFusion.  In fact, when you install ColdFusion (on Windows) you'll notice that the Date Modified on cfencode.exe is 5/23/2001.  It is laid down with this date because during ColdFusion's build process it is still grabbing the same old cfencode.exe file from way back in CF5 days (CF5 was released Spring of 2001).